# selectively convert decimal values (betweeen 0 and 1) into negative inverse

Tags: r, vector

Could anyone help on how can a dataset like, `y <- [1.5, 2, .4, .5, 0 ]` be converted to `[1.5, 2,-2.25, -2, 0 ]`

i.e. [1.5, 2,-1/.4, -1/.5, 0 ]

thanks!

Comment: So, the rule is: if 0<value<1, newvalue=-1/value else newvalue=value, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the rules correctly, something like this would work :
`ifelse(y>1 | y==0 , y, -1/y)`

Comment: Mmmmm. Dunno. @Polar.Ice , what is the value of `y` when `x==1`?

Comment: Thanks for the `ifelse`!!
Y = 1 when its 1. 
Btw, i found  `ifelse(y<1, y, -1/y)` is a bit shorter, yet works fine, as there are no negative values.